# How to include column in resultset without including it in group by clause or performing any aggregation on it?

Tags: sql

Given a list containing City, EmpName and Salary, sorted by city and EmpName, how to output each EmpName and Salary with the total Salary per City?

Here is what I have got:

select EmpName, sum(Salary) from table group by province;

But it gives me error as I have not included the EmpName in the group by clause and/or am not performing any aggregation on it. How can i achieve the desired results? Any help?

Comment: Change the select to "select province, sum(Salary)".

Comment: But i need to display the EmpName as well

Comment: `SUM` is an aggregation function, making non-aggregating columns required to be _grouped by_.

Comment: I'm curious.  WHy do you want the sum and not the average?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, what you want, is the sum of the salary in the city for each employee, then you have two options.  The first should work in almost any database:

```
select EmpName, tcity.CitySalary
from t join
     (select City, sum(Salary) as CitySalary
      from t
      group by city
     ) tcity
     on tcity.city = t.city
```

The second way is to use a window function.  Notably, this doesn't work on mysql:

```
select EmptName, sum(salary) over (partition by city)
from t
```

Comment: Window function indeed way to go here if your RDBMS supports it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.City, t.EmpName, t.Salary, x.city_salary
FROM   table t,
       (SELECT City, SUM(Salary) as city_salary
        FROM   table
        GROUP BY City) x
WHERE x.city = t.city;
```